# Powershell: Issue while calling a powershell script from another powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script `A.ps1`  as below:

```
param([switch] $p1, [switch] $p2)

if ($p1.IsPresent)
{
    $p1 = 2
    & $B -onboardingId "" -p1 $p1.IsPresent $message = "Deployment In Progress" -connectionString $connectionString
}
elseif ($p2.IsPresent)
{
    $p2 = 3
  & $B -onboardingId "" -p2 $p2.IsPresent $message = "Deployment In Progress" -connectionString $connectionString
}
```

The script `A.ps1` is calling `B.ps1` from itself. Both the scripts are placed in the same path. But I am getting the error below when I try to call script:

The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.

> I tried `-ArgumentList` but it did not work out for me.

I tried to resolve the issue by referring online but I was not able to resolve it. Can I please get help on this?
Thank you.

Comment: where is `$b` assigned?

Comment: and `$p1 = 2` and `$p2 = 3` is wrong. those variables are constrained to be of a `[switch]` type. assigning any other value than a boolean, `[switch]::Present` or `$null` is wrong and will be an error in windows powershell.

Comment: If your script B.ps1 also expects switches in `p1` and `p2`, then why not simply send both through as they are and let B.ps1 decide what to do when one or both are present?